# Is cv.glmnet overfitting the the data by using the full lambda sequence?

Tags: r, statistics, cross-validation, glmnet

`cv.glmnet`  has been used by most research papers and companies. While building a similar function like `cv.glmnet` for `glmnet.cr` (a similar package that implements the lasso for continuation ratio ordinal regression) I came across this problem in `cv.glmnet`.

```
`cv.glmnet` first fits the model:



glmnet.object = glmnet(x, y, weights = weights, offset = offset, 
                     lambda = lambda, ...)
```

After the `glmnet` object is created with the complete data, the next step goes as follows:
The `lambda` from the complete model fitted is extracted

```
lambda = glmnet.object$lambda
```

Now they make sure number of folds is more than 3

```
if (nfolds < 3) 
stop("nfolds must be bigger than 3; nfolds=10 recommended")
```

A list is created to store cross validated results

```
outlist = as.list(seq(nfolds))
```

A `for loop` runs to fit different data parts per the theory of cross-validation

```
  for (i in seq(nfolds)) {
    which = foldid == i
    if (is.matrix(y)) 
      y_sub = y[!which, ]
    else y_sub = y[!which]
    if (is.offset) 
      offset_sub = as.matrix(offset)[!which, ]
    else offset_sub = NULL
#using the lambdas for the complete data 
    outlist[[i]] = glmnet(x[!which, , drop = FALSE], 
                          y_sub, lambda = lambda, offset = offset_sub, 
                          weights = weights[!which], ...)
  }
}
```

So what happens. After fitting the data to the complete data, cross-validation is done, with lambdas from the complete data. Can someone tell me how this can possibly not be data over-fitting?. We in cross-validation want the model to have no information about the left out part  of  the data. But `cv.glmnet` cheats on this!

Comment: I suspect this should be discussed on stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: That comment refers to the _sequence of lambda values_ for the complete dataset. The individual crossvalidation models are still fitted to the subsetted data.

Comment: The `lambdas` have seen the full data, which is not right. `lambda` is function of the data and not the data being a function of `lambda`.

Comment: The sequence of steps is this: (1) generate full solution path for all values of lambda based on the full data (2) do CV (2a) fit full solution path to each fold (2b) compute predictions for validation data (left-out data) for each fold and for each lambda (2c) compute error measure for predictions and aggregate these over folds. Now you have a measure of prediction error for each lambda. (3) pick the lambda for which CV error was minimal and report coefficients for full data fit for that lambda.

Comment: Thanks @fabians for the steps. Step (1) is exactly the problem. Why will you use the full data to get an idea of the full solution path?.

Comment: Because of course ultimately the solution should come from an estimate that is based on the full data set (otherwise you're throwing away information). The point of CV is to NOT use the full dataset for finding the value of the tuning parameter in order to avoid overfitting. This is why the value of the tuning parameter lambda is determined based on the prediction errors from the CV, i.e., from the errors on data that were not used to fit the respective CV models.

Comment: I suspect that part of the confusion might be (apologies if I'm wrong)  that you're not entirely clear on the concept of a solution path for LARS/LASSO etc models...?

Comment: Of course CV is to see how well the data predicts and independent data set. With getting the full lambda path from the full data using this full lambda path as source of lambda for sub data makes the left out part not independent of the fitting part. Why because both of them have seen the lambda. Your step (2a) says fit full solution path to each fold and each **lambda** is this **lambda**  from full data or sub data?. If it is from the full data then I repeat it does not seem right. If it is from the sub data why did they fit the lambda on the full data in the first place?

Comment: As I suspected, I think your confusions stems from the fact that the concept of a solution path for LARS/LASSO/etc seems to be unclear to you: every model like that has coefficient paths that describe how the solution changes from the most severe penalty (forces all coefficients to 0) to the most lenient penalty (corresponds to the MaxLik / OLS solution). The challenge is which point on those paths to use, i.e. which lambda.

Comment: In order to find the range of lambdas for which anything interesting happens in your data, you have to look at the full data first, since it does not make sense to compute those parts of the solution paths where all coefficients are already zero or all coefficients are already equal to the MaxLik/OLS solution. Does that help?

Comment: posted for [@Tyler](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6906250/tyler): Chamberlain, were you ever successful in building a glmnet.cr equivalent of cv.glmnet? If so, is it publicly available?

Comment: lambda is not the actual individual model coefficients. It's just the (sequence of) regularization penalty. Hence no overfitting.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that using a cross-validated measure of fit to pick the "best" value of a tuning parameter introduces an optimistic bias into that measure when viewed as an estimate of the out-of-sample performance of the model with that "best" value. Any statistic has a sampling variance. But to talk of *over-fitting* seems to imply that optimization over the tuning parameter results in a degradation of out-of-sample performance compared to keeping it at a pre-specified value (say zero). That's unusual, in my experience—the optimization is very constrained (over a single parameter) compared to many other methods of feature selection. In any case it's a good idea to validate the whole procedure, including the choice of tuning parameter, on a hold-out set, or with an outer cross-validation loop, or by bootstrapping. See [Cross Validation (error generalization) after model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5918/cross-validation-error-generalization-after-model-selection).

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not overfitting.

`cv.glmnet()` does build the entire solution path for the lambda sequence. But you never pick the last entry in that path. You typically pick `lambda==lambda.1se` (or `lambda.min`) , as @Fabians said:

```
lambda==lambda.min : is the lambda-value where cvm is minimized

lambda==lambda.1se : is the lambda-value where (cvm-cvsd)=cvlow is minimized. This is your optimal lambda
```

See the documentation for `cv.glmnet()` and `coef(..., s='lambda.1se')`