# cross validated predictions using glmnet

Tags: cross-validation, glmnet

Does anyone know if glmnet produces cross-validated predictions ie  predictions based on the fold that was left out of the model building (what one usually thinks of as cross-validated) rather than cross-validated predictions being predictions all from the same model based on an optimal lambda which is established by cross-validation ?

Comment: I like the suggestion for an "outer cross-validation loop" in this post and its link "In any case it's a good idea to validate the whole procedure, including the choice of tuning parameter, on a hold-out set, or with an outer cross-validation loop, or by bootstrapping. See Cross Validation (error generalization) after model selection." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825652/is-cv-glmnet-overfitting-the-the-data-by-using-the-full-lambda-sequence

Comment: But how can this be done in R ? I'd like each observation to have a cross-validated prediction - ie the obervation in question is not use in its prediction at al - is that automatic in cv.glmnet (is that what "predict" produces) - or do I need to produce an outer CV loop "manually" ie a for loop - or can caret (using train or some other function) be used ?

Answer (score 2):

`predict.cv.glmnet` just passes the 'glmnet' fit for all of the data to `predict.glmnet` as you suspect.

However, the argument *keep* returns predictions for the training data (fitted values) based on the left-out datasets. The fold each record is assigned to is recorded as the element *foldid*.

```
> library(glmnet)
> # keep prevalidated array
> cvf1 <- cv.glmnet(x = as.matrix(mtcars[, c("disp", "hp", "mpg")]), 
+     y = mtcars$am, family = "binomial", keep = TRUE)
> dim(mtcars)
# [1] 32 11
> length(cvf1$lambda)
# [1] 84
> # leave-n out fitted predictions
> # 84 columns, 2 columns padded with NAs
> dim(cvf1$fit.preval)
# [1] 32 86
> # performance of cross-validated model predictions
> round(mtcars$am - cvf1$fit.preval[, cvf1$lambda == cvf1$lambda.min])
#  [1]  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0
# [16]  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
# [31]  0  0
> cvf1$foldid
#  [1]  1  6  6  1  1  8  9  6  2  5  9  4  4  2  2
# [16] 10  5  2  3  4 10  3  1  3 10  9  7  8  7  8
# [31]  7  5
```

Comment: so if I add the keep=TRUE to cv.glmnet then cvf1$fit.preval will include the actuall CVed predicted values for each item - the same CVed predicted values that contribute to the process of minimising the CVed predictions to find an optimal lambda - brilliant !

Comment: one tiny thing still confuses me - there are 84 candidate lambdas considered (from length(cvf1$lambda) ) - but the matrix cvf1$fit.preval has the predictions for each of the 32 cars in 32 rows with the predictions for the lamdbas in each column - but there are 86 columns (not 84) - I can see column 86 is empty in this case but there are still 85 columns of data for 84 lambdas  -the performance line you give makes it look at though the predictions for the best lambda (number 56) are in columns 56, does that mean the values for the 84 lambdas are in the first 84 columns ? what is in column 85 ?